# Flask python вывод с POST

Tags: python, html, css, post, flask

Всем привет, хочу на новую страницу вывести все данные с POST html код полностью рабочий, проблема где то здесь

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")\

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/registration", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def registration():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["nm"]
        second_name = request.form["snm"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        passwd = request.form["pswd"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr = user, snm = second_name, em = email, pwd = passwd))
    else:
        return render_template("registration.html")

@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr, snm, em, pwd):
    return f"<h1>Имя: {usr}</h1><h1>Фамилия: {snm}</h1><h1>Е-майл: {em}</h1><h1>Пароль: {pwd}</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: `код полностью рабочий, проблема где то здесь` - если рабочий, то какая проблема?

Comment: код html и css рабочий, код flask нерабочий

Comment: В каком смысле "нерабочий"? Что ожидаете и что получаете?

Comment: Я не понимаю, что не понятного в коде, я хочу получить страницу вывода имени, фамилии, емайла и пароля